# Statistics on review home page

Tags: feature-request, review, statistics

On the main 'review' page, can we have a box (or something else) which displays the number of review the user has done of that review type?

Comment: Couldn't get you. What do you mean by *the number of edits the user has done of that type*? Please explain in detail.

Comment: On the main page, I see different categories of edist had can be done : "First posts", "Late answers" and so on. On the right side, we see the icons of the latest reviewers and on going over the icon, you see the number of edits done by that user for today, the current week and the current month. What I am asking for is a similar system   for the current user. As it stands, I have to select that particular type of edit and then I get to see my stats. A popup displaying these stats over some icon would be nice.

Comment: Ah I think you mean number of *review* not *edit*. What you are calling *edit* is actually *review* not *edit*.

Comment: @hims056 Quite so. Thanks!

Comment: I know the words "badge progress" implies that it stops after you've attained the badge but it doesn't, which means you're effectively asking for the same thing.